# Encoding on PostgreSQL, Python, Jinja2

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, flask, jinja2

I'm having a problem with encoding in my application and didn't find the solution anywhere on web.

Here is the scenario:

- PostgreSQL with UTF-8 encoding (`CREATE DATABASE xxxx WITH ENCODING 'UTF8'`)
- Python logic also with UTF-8 encoding (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`)
- Jinja2 to show my HTML pages. Python and Jinja2 are used on Flask, which is the microframework I'm using.

The header of my pages have: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`

Well, using psycopg2 to do a simple query and print it on Jinja2, this is what I get:

```
{% for company in list %}
    <li>
        {{ company }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

(1, 'Casa das M\xc3\xa1quinas', 'R. Tr\xc3\xaas, Mineiros - Goi\xc3\xa1s')

(2, 'Ar do Z\xc3\xa9', 'Av. S\xc3\xa9tima, Mineiros - Goi\xc3\xa1s')

If I try do get more deep into the fields:

```
{% for company in list %}
    <li>
        {% for field in company %}
            <li>
                {{ field }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
 {% endfor %}
```

I get the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

However, if I do a print of the list fields before sending them to Jinja2, I get the expected result (which is also how is presented in postgresql):

1 
Casa das Máquinas
R. Três, Mineiros - Goiás

2
Ar do Zé
Av. Sétima, Mineiros - Goiás

When I get the error, Flask offers an option to "debug". This is where the code breaks
File "/home/anonimou/Desktop/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/_markupsafe/_native.py", line 21, in escape
return Markup(unicode(s)

And I can also do:

```
[console ready]

>>> print s
Casa das Máquinas

>>> s
'Casa das M\xc3\xa1quinas'

>>> unicode(s)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> s.decode('utf-8')
u'Casa das M\xe1quinas'

>>> s.encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> s.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
'Casa das M\xc3\xa1quinas'

>>> print s.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
Casa das Máquinas

>>> print s.decode('utf-8')
Casa das Máquinas
```

I've already tried to break the list, decode, encode, in python code before sending it to Jinja2. The same error.

Sooo, not sure what I can do here. =(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this progressive rock?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that [psycopg2 returns *byte strings* by default in Python 2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#unicode-handling):

> When reading data from the database, in Python 2 the strings returned are usually 8 bit `str` objects encoded in the database client encoding

So you can either:

- Manually decode all of the data to UTF-8:

  ```
  # Decode the byte strings into Unicode objects using
  # the encoding you know that your database is using.
  companies = [company.decode("utf-8") for company in companies]
  return render_template("companies.html", companies=companies)
  ```

*or*

- Set the encoders when you first import psycopg2 as per the note in the same section of the manual:

  > **Note** In Python 2, if you want to uniformly receive all your database input in Unicode, you can register the related typecasters globally as soon as Psycopg is imported:

  ```
  import psycopg2
  import psycopg2.extensions
  psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
  psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY)
  ```

  > and then forget about this story.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the 2nd alternative, which is less "code invasive" for me. Worked fine.

Comment: Great man, you help to solve my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347924/python-unicodedecodeerror-utf8