# Python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8'

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, python-unicode

I'm having problem to save accented letters. I'm using POSTGRESQL and Python 2.7

```
POSTGRESQL -  ENCODING = 'LATIN1'
```

I already added this line but does not worked!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

More about error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xed
```

Please, any idea how to fix it?

@Edit:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
rows = cur.fetchall()


obj_list = list()
for row in rows:
 ob = dict() 
 ob['ID'] = row[0]
 ob['NAME'] = row[1]
 ob['CITY'] = row[2]
 ob['USERNAME'] = row[3]

 obj_list.append(ob)

# print obj_list
# sys.exit()
def add_object(ob, row):
 ws.cell(column=3, row=row).value = ob['ID']
 ws.cell(column=4, row=row).value = ob['NAME']
 ws.cell(column=6, row=row).value = ob['CITY']
 ws.cell(column=8, row=row).value = ob['USERNANE']
```

This part of code is triggering the error. It's returning accent..

```
ob['CITY'] = row[2]
```

Comment: How about showing us the part of the program that's causing the Exception? Please show how you're opening your files/streams and how you're reading from/writing to them.

Comment: What do you mean by "It's returning accent"? The statement is an assignment which you say raises an exception. Assignments don't return anything. Statements that raise an exception can't return anything.

Comment: Acute accent, words "é", "há" are examples, that kind of characters are returning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check is whether your "accented letters" belong to LATIN1 set - for example, á does, but ś doesn't. If not, you really should use UTF8 encoding in PostgreSQL (it is probably safer anyway).

Comment: sorry, but how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: I can not modify anything about PostgreSQL.

Comment: Ah, so you already have LATIN1 in your Postgres database, but you haven't told Python that is is LATIN1, so Python is assuming UTF-8 instead. Call `conn.set_client_encoding('LATIN1')` before `cur.execute` and it should decode correctly.

Comment: Even I called `conn.set_client_encoding('LATIN1')` before cur.. Python's still assuming UTF-8, making impossible I see the "accent characters". Error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8'` continues

Comment: I found out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881467/encoding-on-postgresql-python-jinja2.. What was missing it was these psycopg2.extensions imports. Thanks Błotosmętek